# Should I migrate SSIS packages from version 2015 to 2017?

Tags: sql-server, ssdt-2017

I have recently made a switch from SSDT2015 to SSDT 2017. Should I upgrade my SSIS packages to work in my SSDT2017 or no upgrade is required?

Comment: Have you tried running your packages in SSDT 2017? Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: yes i have tried this and i getting a warning in script task as it shows a warning that SSIS integration package 2012 <Script task name> has to be migrated but it works properly when I run through Visual Studio or SSMS job.